# Connection two-grid, multigrid and finite elements

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, multigrid

In some literature for the two grid method the finite element method is given as an introduction to the topic.

But why is it done that way and where is the connection between these methods?

The finite element method shows how to solve a PDE using a system of linear equations.

The two grid method is a method for solving a linear system.

Is it just that both methods together (first finite elements, then two grid) solve a PDE? Is there  a greater connection?

Comment: Would you solve any linear system with the two-grid method, or are there any assumption on its structure that make the method effective?

Comment: the matrix needs to be symmetric positive definite.

Comment: No. That is a result from the construction via a variational formulation of the PDE. The point is that in the combination of projection, coarse solution and interpolation, the residual is small, so that the refinement stage is actually a refinement and not a full solution of the large system.